# How to approve or disprove a statement-Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm

> For all functions `f`, `log_2(f(n)) + O(n) = O(n)`.

I have tried disapproving it by taking the limit. But got infinity as a result. Is it right?

Comment: big-Oh notation has nothing to do with the limit

Comment: what do you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is not true. As a counterexample `f(n) = n^n`. Therefore, `log(f(n)) = n log(n)` and `n log n + O(n)` is not in `O(n)`.